# Map 127.0.0.1:81 to external ip?

Tags: windows-7, webserver, website, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I host my website on Windows Vista at home computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/97879/how-can-i-host-my-website-on-windows-vista-at-home-computer)

Hi Guys,

I am wondering how I can map my development website - hosted via 127.0.0.1:81 - to an external IP address so it can be accessed from outside my PC ?

I have a static IP address - [example] 11.111.111.11 - and want to be able to show the website to clients via allowing them to view the site ?

Would anyone be able to explain this for Win7 ?

Comment: Duplicate of at least http://superuser.com/questions/97879/how-can-i-host-my-website-on-windows-vista-at-home-computer

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: hey heavyd - using IIS - basically I justed want to be able to show the site externally. maybe i need to check out dynamicDNS but didnt want to go down that road .... thought there would be an easier way to "forward" or something ?

Comment: Are you behind a router/firewall?

Answer (score 0):

How about listening to 0.0.0.0:81 instead so that all requests are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

If your localhost ip is assigned by a router, then you need to determine the ip of the router itself, and then open a port on the router to forward to the port on the machine where the server lives. So, the specific steps for this depends on the router you're using.

I, for example, use an Apple Airport, so I open up my  Airport Utility, go to Advanced, Port Forwarding and open a port (:81 if it's not already taken) that forwards to (my equiv of) 127.0.0.1.:81.

Comment: ah great - ok ill give this a try thx

Answer (score 0):

I think that by default IIS will lock you down on the port and not restrict your IP address. So basically you will have to open the port as said by tmo256 and check with http://www.canyouseeme.org if your port has been opened to the internet. After that you can let someone else visit your website with the IP and the port listed on that site.