# How can I host my website over the internet with dynamic IP address

Tags: web-hosting, dynamic-ip, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET website I want to host from home, but the problem is I have a dynamic IP address. How can I host it so people all over the world can see it? I can't give them a new IP address each time. Is there an alternative to something like DynDNS?

Please help me, I am unable to proceed.

I've googled enough, but I request the super-users here to help me out.

Comment: [How can I host my website on Windows Vista at home computer?](http://superuser.com/q/97879)

Comment: @Sathya that does not help much. DynDNS is no longer free. Is there a Free alternative?

Answer (score 1):

See [DynDNS alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/dyndns/)

> [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/)
>   No-IP allows you to create up to 3 free Dynamics DNS hosts for private use. You will need to register for a free account, and either
>   update your IP address via their web interface or download their
>   Windows client.
>
> [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org/)
>   Free DNS, Dynamic DNS, Static DNS services; 5 free shared hostnames, use anywhere; Unlimited number of domains per account ;Free
>   subdomain hosting, free domain hosting, free backup dns, reverse...